# the probability that there's an actual tornado if the alarm goes off (discrete math)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

TornadoGuard: If there is a tornado in the users's area, an app has 99% probability of warning the user with a loud alert sound. On the other hand, it has 1% probability of playing the loud alert sound when nothing is wrong.

Suppose that there is a tornado in a certain area 6 days out of 1000.
If the alarm goes off, what is the probability that there's an actual tornado in this area?

solution :so the possible outcomes is 0.006 (the days will have tornado)
the possible outcome that produces is 0.01 (if the alarm goes off)

therefore (0.01)/(0.006) right?

Comment: Think again. 0.01/0.006 is meaningless. Also consider that the alarm also goes off at times when there is no tornado.

Comment: is this complement probability ?

Comment: Do you know how to make a probability tree?  The first branch is whether or not there is a tornado.  The second would be whether or not the alarm sounds (for each branch).  Then you have two probabilities corresponding to an alarm going off.  You want the ratio of correct alarms to all alarms.

Comment: is that on a tree chapter? I haven't gone to chapter yet but I will try to self-learn how to do the tree diagram.Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event of a tornado in the area.

Let $B$ denote the event of the alarm goes off.

Then $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{0.006\cdot0.99}{0.006\cdot0.99+(1-0.006)\cdot0.01}\approx37.41\%$.

Comment: Please note that where the answer says "$0.01$", I did not use "$(1-0.99)$" for a reason. Those two events ("the alarm goes off because of a tornado" and "the alarm goes off mistakenly") are **independent** of each other. It just so happen that in your question, their probabilities sum up to $1$, but they could just as well sum up to any value between $0$ and $2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll denote the events as

$T$ - tornado

$A$ - alarm

And the complements $T^C$, respectivelly $A^C$.

You're asking for $P(T|A)$ and what you have is $P(A|T), P(A|T^C), P(T)$. This is a typical question for the [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem)

Comment: okay I will try again thank you! its on my notes.

Comment: You're welcome. Bayes theorem is arguably one of the most amazing things you will probably encounter in an introductory probability lessons not based on measure theory (which I am guessing is your case), so I highly recommend actually *understanding* it. If you ever get a positive result for a scary disease, you'll thank your understanding of math and calm down a bit :)

Comment: like it's possible that the result is false ? Am I right ? LOL

Comment: Yes. If the test correctly diagnoses the disease in 99% of times it is still entirely possible that you have less than 1% chance of having the disease, depending on how rare it actually it (which makes the false positives much more common). Also it makes you aware of how different $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ can be, which is something non-mathematicians often confuse.